# Scraping past an infinite scroller

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I already identified the other pages through Chrome's Inspect tool. The type is XHR and the pages are differentiated through 2 numbers.
"https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=**30**&format=page-element" is page one, 
"https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=**60**&format=page-element" is page two, 
"https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=**90**&format=page-element" is page three etc.

It continues up until page 990.

Here's my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=60&format=page-element"
html = urlopen(url)

page_count = 0
while page_count < 0:
    url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=%d&format=page-element" %(page_count)
    page_count += 30

html = urlopen(url)
```

What I am aiming for is, to get all the products which are on sale.
Reading the source code using inspect I found out, the items which are on sale have two classes: "price-sale" and "price-standard".

Here I was trying to get all the products, using the code above to crack the infinite scroller, and get all products with a sale in a list.

```
def retrieve_products_sale():
    all_products = soup.find_all('li', class_='grid-tile')
    num_of_prods = []
    for items in all_products:
        if items == class_'price-standard':
            num_of_prods.append(items)
    print(num_of_prods)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve_products_sale()
```

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Let me add:
My end goal is to scrape all products which are on sale in a list. Both how many products, and by how many percent each item.

Comment: inside `while` use `urlopen(url)`, `soup = BeautifulSoup(...)` and `retrieve_products_sale(soup)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create that while loop within the function and use `.select()` instead of `find_all()` in order to avoid defining exrta looping to filter out desired items.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"

def fetch_items(link,page):
    while page<=100:
        print("current page no: ",page)
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for items in soup.select('.grid-tile .price-standard'):
            product_list.append(items)

        print(product_list)
        page+=30

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 0
    product_list = []
    fetch_items(url,page)
```

Comment: this is perfect! Works like a dream. Now I only need it to spit out a number of how many items there is in the last list.

Answer (score 0):

it could be something like this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

def retrieve_products_sale(soup):
    all_products = soup.find_all('li', class_='grid-tile')
    num_of_prods = []
    for items in all_products:
        if items == class_'price-standard':
            num_of_prods.append(items)
    print(num_of_prods)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_count = 0        
    while page_count <= 990:
        url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=%d&format=page-element" % page_count
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        retrieve_products_sale(soup)
        page_count += 30
```

If you need all data in one list then use list outside function

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

def retrieve_products_sale(soup):
    all_products = soup.find_all('li', class_='grid-tile')
    num_of_prods = []
    for items in all_products:
        if items == class_'price-standard':
            num_of_prods.append(items)
    #print(num_of_prods)
    return num_of_prods

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_count = 0      
    all_results = []  
    while page_count <= 990:
        url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=%d&format=page-element" % page_count
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        all_results += retrieve_products_sale(soup)
        page_count += 30

    print(all_results)
```

---

**EDIT:** I don't know what you try do do with

```
 if items == class_'price-standard':
```

so I use

```
 for x in items.find_all(class_='price-standard'):
```

which gives some results (but not on all pages)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

def retrieve_products_sale(soup):
    all_products = soup.find_all('li', class_='grid-tile')
    num_of_prods = []
    for items in all_products:
        for x in items.find_all(class_='price-standard'):
            #print(x)
            num_of_prods.append(x)
    print(num_of_prods)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_count = 0        
    while page_count <= 990:
        url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start=%d&format=page-element" % page_count
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        retrieve_products_sale(soup)
        page_count += 30
```

Comment: It gives me an error:   File "<ipython-input-3-047a52cc6832>", line 8
    if items == class_'price-standard':
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I copied your code `if items == class_'price-standard':` so you made mistake in this line. What do you try to do here ?

Comment: My code is by far not perfect :) I was trying to say "if it finds any classes with 'price-standard' which refers to a product being on sale, then add it to the list"

Comment: I added code which works and display some elements with class `'price-standard'`. Now you can modify it.

Comment: It looks like its working. Thanks a lot. The thing is not all the items are on sale, and those that are have both a price-sales and price-standard. I have to figure out how to navigate that.